# Clicking the add button adds the value to all same value in product_stock

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

When I click the add button it adds The values of Textbox4 to All Same Value in product_stock in the data base.

```
conn.Open()
    Using com As New SqlCommand("UPDATE table_addsub SET [product_stock]=[product_stock] + @qty2 WHERE [product_stock]=@qty1", conn)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty1", Me.TextBox3.Text)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty2", Me.TextBox4.Text)
        com.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully")
        LoadList()
    End Using
```

[image]

The Product Stock of Nail and Bulb is 100 but when i want to add 20 to the stock of bulb it also add 20 to the Stock of Nail

Comment: Code under the `LoadList()` ? and Verify u r `UPDATE` Statement `WHERE` Clause. wrong in u r logic at Where Clause.

Comment: Thats all, its the code for button add. When i click add button it add the quantity in Textbox4 to all the same value in product_stock in sql server which is wrong. I want this to happen, when i click add button it will add the quantity in textbox4 to the quantity in textbox3 whick is the product_stock in sql server.

Comment: But u r missing Product_id….

Comment: I Fixed it, Thank you sir. :)

Comment: My mistake is i'm calling the product_stock instead of product_id. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Ya.. That's what I am Saying... and given answer below.. Go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing Product Id in `WHERE` Clause.

```
conn.Open()
Using com As New SqlCommand("UPDATE table_addsub SET [product_stock]=[product_stock] + @qty2 WHERE [product_Id]=@Prod_Id", conn)
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prod_Id", Me.TextBox3.Text) // Product id        
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty2", Me.TextBox4.Text) //Qty to be add.
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully")
    LoadList()
End Using
```